# I want my app to start automatically every month on a particular day

Tags: android, alarm

I want my app to start automatically every month on a particular day(Specified by user).
I searched a lot on Google, but I din get any solution. I got alarm for seconds like the app starts after a particular seconds. I am new to android. So an example will be highly appreciated

Answer (score 3):

You are looking for the [**AlarmManager**](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html) class.
Quoting from the documentation,

> This class provides access to the system alarm services. These allow
>   you to schedule your application to be run at some point in the
>   future.

Answer (score 0):

create a service with alarm manager ...........
and start the app when particular date comes